# How to make the m2m_changed signal atomic in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

I have the following models in my project:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Saving...')
        if self.pk:
            for topping in self.toppings.all():
                print(topping.name)

        super(Pizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def toppings_changed(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.save()

m2m_changed.connect(toppings_changed, sender=Pizza.toppings.through)
```

Basically, whenever `toppings` is changed, the signal is fired. All the signal does is call the `Pizza` object's save method. Anyway, lets say I have three objects:

```
pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=1) # Number of toppings is 0
topping1 = Topping.objects.get(pk=1)
topping2 = Topping.objects.get(pk=2)
```

Now, I want to set the two toppings to my pizza. I do this using the following code:

```
pizza = Pizza.objects.get(pk=1)
pizza.toppings.set([1, 2])
```

The toppings are set correctly, however, the pizza's save method is called twice, because the m2m_changed signal is called twice, as there are two changes happening. How can I call this only once after all of the changes has been committed? To clarify, I want both of the toppings to be added, but I want to fire my signal only once, at the end of all the changes. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `m2m_changed` signal is slightly strange, in that it is called twice: once with an action of `pre_add`, and once with an action of `post_add` (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#m2m-changed)). Since you're calling `toppings_changed()` for any action, it will end up being called twice, hence `save()` will be called twice.

It looks like you're interested in `post_add`, so I would do something like:

```
@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=Pizza.toppings.through)
def toppings_changed(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == "post_add":
        instance.save()
```

Here, `instance.save()` should only be called once, no matter how many arguments you're passing to `set()`. Note that you won't need to do `m2m_changed.connect(...)` if you use the receiver decorator.

The above also applies to `pre/post_remove` and `pre/post_clear`, so if you want to print your list after a removal, you'll need to add some more logic to check if `action == "post_remove"`.

Finally, just in case you're unaware, `set([1, 2])` will **replace** all of your toppings with the two you provided (`pk=1` and `pk=2`). If you simply want to add toppings to your existing set, i'd use `add(1, 2)`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Really good answer. Thanks a lot. One question though, setting the logic as `if action == 'post_add' or action == 'post_remove' or action == 'post_delete':` does not really call the save method if a related `Topping` object is deleted. For add, and remove, it works perfectly. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ahh my bad! I typed `post_delete` instead of `post_remove` by accident (edited now). `m2m_changed` only receives pre/post `_add`, `_remove` and `_clear` actions. A `post_delete` signal is separate, and you'll need to attach another `@receiver` to your function. In your case, it will look like: `@receiver(post_delete, sender=Topping)`.

To clarify; `post_delete` is called when a topping object is deleted, and `post_remove` is called when a topping is removed from a pizza (not necessarily deleted all together).